# Cyclic group of order $n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

> Let $n$ be any integer. We construct a group of order $n$ as  follows:
>   $G$ will consist of all symbols $a^i$, $i=0,1,2 \cdots, n-1$ where we
>   insist $a^0 = a^n = e$, $a^{i}\cdot a^{j} = a^{i+j}$ if $i+j \le n$
>   and $a^{i}\cdot a^{j} = a^{i+j-n}$ if $i+j > n.$ The reader may verify
>   that this is a group. It is called a cyclic group of order $n$.

I'm trying to verify that this indeed is a group.

(a) For any $a^i, a^j \in G$ we have $a^i\cdot a^j = a^{i+j} \in G$ if $i+j \le n$; and $a^i\cdot a^j = a^{i+j-n} \in G$ if $i+j > n$.

(b) For any $a^i, a^j, a^k \in G$, for $i+j+k \le n$ we have $a^i \cdot ( a^j \cdot a^k) = a^i \cdot a^{j+k} = a^{i+j+k}$ since $j+k \le n$ is implied by $i+j+k \le n.$ If $i+j+k > n$ we have $a^i \cdot ( a^j \cdot a^k) = a^i \cdot a^{j+k}$ $= a^{i+j+k-n}$ if $j+k \le n$; and if $j+k > n$ we have $a^i \cdot ( a^j \cdot a^k) = a^i \cdot a^{j+k-n}$ $= a^{i+j+k-2n}$.

For any $a^i, a^j, a^k \in G$, for $i+j+k \le n$ we have $(a^i \cdot  a^j) \cdot a^k = a^{i+j} \cdot a^{k} = a^{i+j+k}$ since $i+j \le n$ is implied by $i+j+k \le n.$ If $i+j+k > n$ we have $(a^i \cdot  a^j) \cdot a^k = a^{i+j} \cdot a^{k}$ $= a^{i+j+k-n}$ if $i+j \le n$; and if $i+j > n$ we have $(a^i \cdot  a^j) \cdot a^k = a^{j+k-n} \cdot a^{k}$ $= a^{i+j+k-2n}$.

(c) There's $a^0 \in G$ such that for any $a^i \in G$ we have $a^i \cdot a^0 = a^{i+0} = a^i$ and $a^0a^i = a^{0+i} = a^i.$

(d) For every $a^i \in G$ there's $a^{-i} \in G$ such that $a^i \cdot a^{-i} = a^{i-i} = a^0$ and $ a^{-i} \cdot a^i  = a^{-i+i} = a^0.$

Is this correct?

Comment: For (d) the inverse is given by $a^{n-i}$.  I have not checked (a) and (b).

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks. I wrote (b) wrong by copying by my earlier latex, corrected now. I did suspect that (d) was wrong since $a^{-i} \in G$ does not appear in my definition.

Comment: A little thing is funny about the definition. Either use $a^1,\dots,a^n$ or if you use $a^0,\dots a^{n-1}$ then for $i+j\ge n$ we need to say the product is $a^{i+j-n}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas So the definition isn't quite right as written? In that case, I need to rewrite (a) and (b)? Btw, I copy the definition from Herstein's Topics In Algebra, Chapter 2, section 2, example 4.

Comment: With the identification of $a^n$ with $a^0$, it is OK.  Part (a) is not necessary, it is clear that a multiplication has been defined. Identity and inverse are easy, the only unpleasant thing is associativity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have the operation defined, you'll have a number of cases to check for associativity. Here's one of them, picked at random:

$i+j > n;\ n < (i+j) + k = i + (j+k) < 2n;\ j+k \leq n$.

Then $(a^i\cdot a^j)\cdot a^k  = a^{i+j-n}\cdot a^k = a^{i+j-n+k}$.

(since $n < (i+j) + k < 2n$, then $0 < i+j-n + k < n$).

Now $a^i\cdot (a^j\cdot a^k) = a^i\cdot a^{j+k} = a^{i+j+k-n}$.

But $i+j-n+k = i+j+k-n$.

Note I have used freely associativity and commutativity of integer addition without proof or comment.

In truth, the "$a$" is just a *placeholder*, all the action is happening in the exponents, and there we have the operation of the integers modulo $n$ (addition modulo $n$). It is easier to prove that $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ under addition modulo $n$ is associative (proving it is *well-defined* is the sticky part) than the operation Herstein gives there, because integer addition is associative, and the integers modulo $n$ "inherit" many of the integers' nice properties.